# Super capacitor, water pump

Tags: supercapacitor, transistor-array

I want to design a circuit which can store energy from a little 6 V solar panel into a super capacitor and when it reaches a certain amount of voltage (or gets full) ,  **with a steep start** , it releases its energy into a 500 mW, 3 to 6 V water pump for maximum 6 seconds. **with just transistors no ic`s . but the problem is most of the transistor circuits start gradually .**

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: are you sure your super capacitor can be discharged in 6 seconds? Most of the super capacitors I have seen were rated for slower discharges.

Comment: i am not sure .  please guide me about using super capacitors .

Comment: Please draw a schematic with the tool

Comment: @AliKh if we are done here then you should mark my answer as "accepted" or leave a comment for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

So, if the water pump is 500 mW at (say) 4.5 volts (midway between 3 volts and 6 volts), that's a current of 111 mA. So if the motor can suffer a voltage fall from 6 volts to 3 volts in 6 seconds, that's a dv/dt of 3/6 or 0.5.

Then, rearranging the basic capacitor formula: -

$$I = C\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

We can find capacitance required = 0.222 farads.

> *it suddenly releases its energy into a 500 mW, 3 to 6 V water pump for
> 6 seconds*

You don't want it to suddenly release energy into a pump; you want it to power the pump for 6 seconds and, this doesn't happen with a sudden energy release; you need a gradual and measured release and, that's what you'll get with a simple circuit made using a comparator and MOSFET. You can even use two comparators (aka a window comparator) so that the circuit automatically shuts the pump off and restarts the charging process.

> *I would appreciate your help*

Hep given; you need at least 0.222 farads charged to 6 volts and that will supply an average current of 111 mA for 6 seconds before the terminal voltage drops lower than 3 volts.

Comment: Those 500 mW are probably what the pump consumes in a steady state, startup current draw will be many times higher (perhaps for a few hundred milliseconds), so the minimum required capacitance might be more like 300 mF or so (impossible to say with any certainty without more data on the pump).